# Java: Converter strings delimitadas por ponto para JSON aninhado

Tags: java, hashmap, serialização, json

Eu tenho um monte de atributos vindo como strings delimitadas por ponto como "company.id", "company.address.number", "user.name", "isAtive", e eu preciso criar um JSON aninhado com seus respectivos valores. Esses atributos e valores estão em um HashMap.

Nem tudo tem 3 níveis de profundidade: muitos têm apenas 1 nível de profundidade e muitos são mais profundos que 3 níveis.

Exemplo de código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String[]> list = new HashMap<>();
    list.put("params.isAtive", new String[] {"true"});
    list.put("params.user.name", new String[] {"John Diggle"});
    list.put("params.company.id", new String[] {"1"});
    list.put("params.company.name", new String[] {"SICAL MOTORS"});
    list.put("params.company.address.number", new String[] {"525"});
    list.put("params.company.address.street", new String[] {"Park Avenue"});
    list.put("params.models", new String[] {"55", "65"});
    JSONObject jsonReq = new JSONObject();
    for(Entry<String, String[]> entry : list.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey().replaceAll("params\\.", "");
        String value = entry.getValue().length == 1 ? entry.getValue()[0] : Arrays.toString(entry.getValue());
        String [] spl = key.split("\\.");
        if(spl.length == 1) {
            jsonReq.put(key, value);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
                if(i == spl.length - 1) {
                    jsonReq.getJSONObject(spl[i-1]).put(spl[i], value);
                } else {
                    if((i-1) > 0) {
                        if(!jsonReq.getJSONObject(spl[i-1]).has(spl[i])) {
                            jsonReq.getJSONObject(spl[i-1]).put(spl[i], new JSONObject());
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(!jsonReq.has(spl[i])) {
                            jsonReq.put(spl[i], new JSONObject());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(jsonReq.toString());
}
```

Resultado atual:

```
{"models":"[55, 65]","address":{"number":"525","street":"Park Avenue"},"company":{"name":"SICAL MOTORS","id":"1"},"user":{"name":"John Diggle"},"isAtive":"true"}
```

Resultado esperado:

```
{"models":"[55, 65]","company":{"name":"SICAL MOTORS","id":"1","address":{"number":"525","street":"Park Avenue"}},"user":{"name":"John Diggle"},"isAtive":"true"}
```

Lembrando que não é necessário utilizar JSONObject, se optar por outro não tem problema, só preciso resolver a questão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, veja se isso resolve pra vc

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {

  private static void addEntry(JSONObject jsonReq, String currentkey, String value) {
    String[] keys = currentkey.split("\\.");
    JSONObject newJson = new JSONObject();
    newJson = jsonReq;
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.length-1; i++){
        if (newJson.has(keys[i])) {
            newJson = newJson.getJSONObject(keys[i]);
        }else{
            newJson.put(keys[i], new JSONObject());
            newJson = newJson.getJSONObject(keys[i]);
        }
    }
    newJson.put(keys[keys.length-1], value);
    jsonReq=newJson;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String[]> list = new HashMap<>();
    list.put("params.isAtive", new String[] { "true" });
    list.put("params.user.name", new String[] { "John Diggle" });
    list.put("params.company.id", new String[] { "1" });
    list.put("params.company.name", new String[] { "SICAL MOTORS" });
    list.put("params.company.address.number", new String[] { "525" });
    list.put("params.company.address.street", new String[] { "Park Avenue" });
    list.put("params.models", new String[] { "55", "65" });
    JSONObject jsonReq = new JSONObject();

    for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : list.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey().replaceAll("params\\.", "");;
        String value = entry.getValue().length == 1 ? entry.getValue()[0] : Arrays.toString(entry.getValue());
        addEntry(jsonReq,key, value);
    }
    System.out.println(jsonReq.toString());
 }
}
```

Resultado atual

```
{"models":"[55, 65]","company":{"address":{"number":"525","street":"Park Avenue"},"name":"SICAL MOTORS","id":"1"},"user":{"name":"John Diggle"},"isAtive":"true"}
```

Resultado esperado:

```
{"models":"[55, 65]","company":{"name":"SICAL MOTORS","id":"1","address":{"number":"525","street":"Park Avenue"}},"user":{"name":"John Diggle"},"isAtive":"true"}
```